# Why is TimeSpan.Duration() a method rather than a property?

Tags: c#, methods, properties, timespan, duration

[`TimeSpan.Duration()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you the absolute value of a `TimeSpan`'s duration which can be useful in some circumstances.

It is, however, a method rather than a property of the struct. The very first paragraph of [the MSDN guidelines on choosing a method or a property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx) states:

> In general, methods represent actions and properties represent data.
>   Properties are meant to be used like fields, meaning that properties
>   should not be computationally complex or produce side effects. When it
>   does not violate the following guidelines, consider using a property,
>   rather than a method, because less experienced developers find
>   properties easier to use.
>
> **Consider using a property if the member represents a logical attribute of the type.**

(Emphasis theirs.)

Duration does not appear to violate the "use a method if" section, either.

I thought it might be for backward-compatibility reasons, so I went [back to the property vs method guidelines for .NET 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.80).aspx), and they're relatively unchanged. So then I wondered if .NET 1.1 just didn't have properties, [but it did](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt(v=vs.71).aspx), so I don't *think* that's the reason, either.

Comment: It returns a new `TimeSpan` object -- such a side effect is not something typically expected from a property. The naming is still a little uneasy though.

Comment: Presumably it was an oversight and was simply done contrary to guidelines originally. It happens every now and then. `DateTime.Now` is a notable example of something that gets it "wrong" as well. Unfortunately, once it is in, it is very hard to make a change.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It doesn't have a side-effect; the state of the original TimeSpan is unaltered.

Comment: _It returns a new TimeSpan object -- such a side effect is not something typically expected from a property. The naming is still a little uneasy though._ -- Wow. That's unexpected given the method name. Perhaps a related question might be "Why does `TimeSpan.Duration()` return a new struct?"

Comment: Negate() is another one.  This is a .NET 1.0 type, it was written ~17 years ago.  .NET would certainly have looked a *lot* different if they knew way back then what they know now but even the big boys have to start at version 1.  You'll have to read it as GetDuration() to get past the speed-bump.  That it throws an exception for an uninitialized TimeSpan is perhaps the plausible reason.  Why that was important for Duration() but not for any of the properties is the bigger question.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be this is due to the fact that it can throw an OverflowException in a boundary case.  Generally it's preferable that property getters not throw exceptions (except maybe ObjectDisposedException in some cases), though I'm not aware of a guideline specifically stating this.  This might be covered under the 'produce side effects' guideline, since a thrown exception is certainly a side effect.

Comment: [Here's the guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx) : _"AVOID throwing exceptions from property getters."_

Comment: A thrown exception certainly isn't a side-effect.